# spring mongo query testing

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I would like to set up a test (unit or integration test) for a mongo query. 
I would like to test the following function:

```
 public ArrayList<Document> search(){ 
         Document textSearch = new Document("$text",new 
         Document("$search",text));
         return randomCollection.find(textSearch).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
    }
```

Im using MongoTemplate to get the mongo collection randomCollection

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootTest` can be used to bootstrap all your Spring configurations. If you will write a test (which you should always do, your test will look something like this):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeArbitraryTests {

    @Autowired
    private ArbitraryResource someResource;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        someResource.search(...);
        // assertions
    }
}
```

If you would want to add an Embedded Mongodb for your testing purposes, then you might want to add some additional dependencies to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer i still have something unclear: Im using a @Configuration annotated class to get a mongo bean in the service , how would I switch the real mongo in the service with the embedded mongo so i would be able to test the service, and is this what you have suggested an integration test?